# TensorFlow 2.0 - Running using TPU: AttributeError: 'NameError' object has no attribute 'op'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I'm running code script designed for to work with TF 2.0 to generate predictions on a pre-trained BERT base model for an NLP task. I'm running with with Python 3.7 and TF 2.1 in a Google Colab notebook using a cloud-TPU hosted instance. I'm able to run the script successfully without errors and generate predictions using a cloud-GPU but am getting the following error outputs when I try to run it with a TPU (after enabling the TPU and pointing to the corresponding ip address for the TPU).

```
2020-02-09 01:17:36.155906: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2020-02-09 01:17:36.156040: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2020-02-09 01:17:36.156061: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
WARNING:tensorflow:From tf_kaggle_test.py:188: The name tf.estimator.tpu.InputPipelineConfig is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.InputPipelineConfig instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From tf_kaggle_test.py:189: The name tf.estimator.tpu.RunConfig is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.RunConfig instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From tf_kaggle_test.py:194: The name tf.estimator.tpu.TPUConfig is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.TPUConfig instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From tf_kaggle_test.py:212: The name tf.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimator is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimator instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function model_fn_builder.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f55bb7600d0>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
```

```
FLAGS.predict_file data/simplified-nq-test.jsonl
***** Running predictions *****
  Num orig examples = 346
  Num split examples = 9409
  Batch size = 8
  Num split into 3 = 8
  .
  .
  Num split into 187 = 1
output/eval.tf_record
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1635: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
2020-02-09 01:18:52.589210: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_session.cc:373] GrpcSession::ListDevices will initialize the session with an empty graph and other defaults because the session has not yet been created.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/gdrive/My Drive/Capstone - Google QA/natural-questions-nlp-drive/tf2_0_baseline_w_bert.py:1112: map_and_batch (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map(map_func, num_parallel_calls)` followed by `tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder)`. Static tf.data optimizations will take care of using the fused implementation.
2020-02-09 01:18:53.890592: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/util.py:1262: NameBasedSaverStatus.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Restoring a name-based tf.train.Saver checkpoint using the object-based restore API. This mode uses global names to match variables, and so is somewhat fragile. It also adds new restore ops to the graph each time it is called when graph building. Prefer re-encoding training checkpoints in the object-based format: run save() on the object-based saver (the same one this message is coming from) and use that checkpoint in the future.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/gdrive/My Drive/Capstone - Google QA/natural-questions-nlp-drive/tf2_0_baseline_w_bert.py:1057: The name tf.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec instead.
```

The above warnings all are fine and still run, many of them pointing to the issues due to deprecation as the original script was built for TF 1.0 and then translated to work with TF 2.0. It appears the issue and failure is occurring with the **tpu_estimator** and **error_handling** scripts below; something to do with the exception catching process.  I'm not sure what it's referring to when it refers to the AttributeError: 'NameError' object has no attribute 'op' and name 'assignment_map' is not defined.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Reraising captured error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3075, in predict
    rendezvous.record_error('prediction_loop', sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/error_handling.py", line 81, in record_error
    if value and value.op and value.op.type == _CHECK_NUMERIC_OP_NAME:
AttributeError: 'NameError' object has no attribute 'op'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_kaggle_test.py", line 267, in <module>
    predict_input_fn, yield_single_examples=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3078, in predict
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/error_handling.py", line 143, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3072, in predict
    yield_single_examples=yield_single_examples):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 626, in predict
    features, None, ModeKeys.PREDICT, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2857, in _call_model_fn
    config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1152, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3394, in _model_fn
    scaffold = _get_scaffold(scaffold_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3749, in _get_scaffold
    scaffold = scaffold_fn()
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Capstone - Google QA/natural-questions-nlp-drive/tf2_0_baseline_w_bert.py", line 994, in tpu_scaffold
    tf.compat.v1.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)
NameError: name 'assignment_map' is not defined
```

The notebook where I'm using the script (and it worked perfectly with a GPU/CPU)is located here:
https://www.kaggle.com/abhinand05/bert-for-humans-tutorial-baseline/data#Code-Implementation-in-Tensorflow-2.0

Is it something to do with using the Google Colab that I need to change or additional changes to be made to use with a TPU?